# Objective C - Recognise logo

Tags: ios

I am looking for an open source solution for recognising a logo via the iphone camera. There is some fancy AR products like metaio that cost a lot and do more than i want. I don't want to do any AR when the image is recognised just push a uiviewcontroller. I've been searching on google and not found any sample projects that do what i want. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 'Shopping list' questions usually aren't welcome here - this site is more for questions about specific problems.

Comment: well it is a problem... i cant find anything to build the app im making.. not buying veg here

Comment: What you're really talking about is "image recognition".  You may have more luck looking for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the OpenCV which is suggested everywhere, but its a pain to get your head around. I then stumbled across this http://www.qualcomm.com/solutions/augmented-reality vuforia is a free to use ar product with the option to add mulitple targets and call different methods for different targets. hope this saves someone the 2 days i spent on open cv.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments note, this is a bit of a vague question so here's a vague answer: you'll likely need a "computer vision" library, something like [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/). I have no personal experience with it but know that it can be used for face recognition. Identifying logos is likely to be a similar problem.